# How can I create an alert in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I have the following structure:

- cho_id    int
- cho_nombre varchar(200)
- cho_documento varchar(15)
- cho_dirrecion varchar(100)
- cho_telefono  varchar(15)
- cho_fec_vencimiento_lic **datetime**
- cho_categoria int
- est_id    int

I have a row of datetime type and I want that every time the date approaches send me an alert 15 days before and send me by email.

How can I design this in SQL Server? Does it have to be with stored procedures? Triggers?

Comment: write a stored procedure and set it up as a scheduled job.

Comment: Sounds like an agent job with a simple query and sp_send_dbmail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick shell you can use for a procedure, which you'll then schedule as a job to run daily. You can change the logic of the `IF` as you seem fit.

```
create procedure myProc
as

if (select datediff(day,max(cho_fec_vencimiento_lic),getdate()) from SomeTable) = 15
begin
exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
                    @profile_name = null,
                    @recipients  = 'email@domain.org',
                    @body = 'This is your email alert',
                    @body_format = 'TEXT',
                    @subject = 'Alert'
end
go
```

[sp_dend_dbmail reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-send-dbmail-transact-sql)

[Schedule a job reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: No worries at all @JoseAngel

Comment: One question Simon when you are creating the schedule job at the moment you need to write T-SQL command you want to run can I specify the stored procedure that I want? @scsimon

Comment: Yup... just put exec myProc where myProc is your procedure name. Also since you aren't looking at the time, only the date, I'd  schedule it to run at like 11pm or after all transactions for that day have been made. Otherwise you may want to change the = in the IF statement to <=